# How do I kill a Firefox process thrashing my computer? 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ram, process, kill, ps

In short: a Firefox process takes control of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my Acer TravelMate P, and it seems there's nothing I can do but to shutdown the computer. This is similar to https://superuser.com/questions/248707/how-do-i-quickly-stop-a-process-that-is-causing-thrashing-due-to-excess-memory however, the main answer didn't work for me (some combination with SysRq), and I prefer not to have a script running like @tobixen suggests there.

Comment: "Some combination?" Perhaps you used the wrong combination? Perhaps you did it wrong?

Comment: I tried several including all possible combination of Ctrl, Alt, SysRq, Shift plus F. None of them worked.

Comment: Then how do you know that it's a runaway process instead of a crash?

Comment: I just experienced it again, and it's definitively not memory swap. But I don't know what it is. Mouse is still moving around, and fans are at top speed.

Comment: So far, always while surfing in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl-Alt-T` opens a terminal emulation window.

`ps -ef | grep firefox`  shows the Firefox [processes](https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-linux-ps-command-4058715), or `top` will show processes, memory use, and CPU use.

`kill -9 nnnnn`  where *nnnnn* is the PID number of a suspect process [stops that process](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux). You can specify multiple PIDs in one command line.

Browsers are susceptible to running [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp) of dubious goodness when you stumble upon a malicious website. Often, the website's creator is time sharing ***your*** PC to run mine Bitcoin or such.

Extensions like [NoMiner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nominer-block-coin-miners/) block mining specifically, and other extensions like [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) go further and block Javascript except when you let it run. Javascript is used so widely, for good and bad, that NoScript and other apps will allow you to open up Javascript for specific websites as needed, and will remember when you opened the door for a particular site.

Comment: As said, the problem is the OS becoming unresponsive. Opening a terminal is completely out of the question (either xterm or `Ctrl-Alt-Fn`).

Comment: If you like an answer, click on the checkmark above at left to show you accept the answer. Then it's easier to refer other folks with the same issue to it. (The answer dude also gets 10,000 quatloos in gold-pressed latinum, but IRS takes most of it.)

Answer (score 0):

To close firefox from the terminal, this works:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep firefox | awk '{ print $2 }')
```